# JSON error when calling chart.draw from Google GeoChart library

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, encoding, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google GeoChart library to display a map, and if I do it on a local HTML file or somewhere like JSFiddle, it works perfectly.

However, when I embed it in a JSP on my project and deploy it (using JBoss), calling `chart.draw` results in a JSON error:

```
Invalid JSON string: {":",":",":{":[",","]},":",":{":true}}
```

My complete Javascript method is as follows:

```
var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                                   [{label: 'Country', type: 'string'},
                                                    {label: 'description', type: 'string'},
                                                    {label: 'consistency', type: 'number'},
                                                    {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}],
                                                    ['Canada', "CANADA", 2, "OK"],
                                                    ['France', "FRANCE", 0, "KO"],
                                                    ['USA', "USA", 1, "Other"]
                                                 ]);    

var options = {
        displayMode: 'region',
        backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
        colorAxis: {
            colors: ['red', 'orange', 'green']
        },
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {
            showColorCode: true
        }
    };

 var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
 chart.draw(data2, options);
```

So it's clearly picking up the "structure" of the JSON object (two simple objects, another object with an array inside, another simple object, another object with an array inside), but for some reason is not picking up the content, except for the 'true' value, so it looks like a problem with quotes...

In any case, I have tried simple and double quotes, removing the quotes from the identifiers, reducing the `options` object to a simple

```
var options = {
     "legend": "none"
};
```

... but to no avail. Everything results in a `Invalid JSON string` error (in this last case, a `Invalid JSON string: {":"}` error, since there is only one object).

Last note: if I just use

```
var options = {};
```

it shows the map (but with the default options).

Any ideas as to why is this happening and/or how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Any console error in developer tools?

Comment: Nope, nothing, just the JSON error message instead of the map in the div :(

Comment: Can you show your call method from Google?

Comment: I have just edited the question and added more details (thanks!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6024803/3030495 you can find it here

Comment: Thanks for trying... but it didn't work :( I tried `eval(options)` and I got the same error, and `eval("("+options+")")` got me a "Unexpected identifier" error in the Javascript console, and trying to open it only shows `([object Object])`

Comment: Can you try with addColumn() ? . Bcs your error is data.

Comment: I tried, but the error is in `options`, not in data (with no options, the map is being shown). I suspect something related with the quotes, but I don't know what can it be :(